# How to send email using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, email

I created an application. Before using the application, the user must register with us. When they come for registration, they need to fill in their name, phone number, and email address. When they click on the "register" button, a confirmation message gets sent to the user's registered email address. This confirmation message contain a token to activate the user account. After that they will be able to set the password for their account.

However, my program is not able to send the confirmation to the registered email address. I added Java mail sender in my gradle file. Here is my Consumer entity class

```
package com.nilmani.testthymeleaf.entity

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.Email
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty

@Entity
data class Consumer(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a name")
    val firstName:String="",
    @Column(unique = true)
    val phoneNumber:Long=-1,
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email(message = "Please provide an valid email")
    val email:String="",
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password cannot be empty")
    var password:String="",
    var enabled:Boolean=false,
    var confirmationToken:String="",
)
```

Controller class

```
 @PostMapping("/SignUp")
    fun registerConsumer(modelAndView: ModelAndView,@Valid consumer: Consumer,
                         result:BindingResult,request:ServletRequest):ModelAndView{
        val existingUser : Consumer? = consumerRepository.findByEmail(consumer.email)
        println(existingUser)
        if (existingUser != null){
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage","Oops!  There is already a user registered with the email provided.")
            modelAndView.viewName = "SignUp"
            result.reject("email")
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            modelAndView.viewName ="SignUp"
        }else{
            consumer.enabled=false
            //Generate auto matic 16 digit token to verify the email
            consumer.confirmationToken =UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            consumerRepository.save(consumer)
            var appUrl = request.scheme + "://" + request.serverName
            var registrationEmail = SimpleMailMessage()
            registrationEmail.setTo(consumer.email)
            registrationEmail.setSubject("Registration Confirmation")
            registrationEmail.setText(
                """
                To confirm your e-mail address, please click the link below:
                $appUrl/confirm?token=${consumer.confirmationToken}
                """.trimIndent()
            )
            registrationEmail.setFrom("noreply@domain.com")
            emailService.sendEmail(registrationEmail)
            modelAndView.addObject("confirmationMessage","A confirmation e-mail has send to "+consumer.email)
            modelAndView.viewName = "SignUp"
        }
        return modelAndView
    }
```

The above function is my consumer registration.
ConsumerRepository Interface

```
package com.nilmani.testthymeleaf.repository

import com.nilmani.testthymeleaf.entity.Consumer
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface ConsumerRepository : JpaRepository<Consumer,Long> {

    fun findByEmail(email:String?):Consumer?
    fun findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken:String):Consumer
}
```

Why is my code not able to send the email to registered
address? I can see no error code. I don't understand the behaviour of my code. Where is the problem?

Comment: You should describe the current behavior of your code : what exactly are you getting as a result when your try your code?

Comment: No confirmation  message send to the registered email address,But my requirement is user get a confirmation message in her inbox

Comment: I mean if an exception is thrown during email sending. Or it just returns normally? Also, check this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Comment: No there is no exception,It returns normally

Comment: then I don't know what could be the problem. First, add your configuration/code of service that sends the email. Maybe mail server is not configured properly and the email is just dropped. Wait for other users to respond.